# Cannot read property length angularjs

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I have the following piece of code in an angular app that i generated using yeoman

```
'use strict';

function CoffeeListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/coffee.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.coffees = data;
  });
    $scope.orderProp = 'name';
    $scope.orderType = '';

    $scope.goTo = function (path) {
        $location.path(path);
    }

$scope.showNresults = function (n) {
        if (n==-1) {
            return $scope.coffees.length;
        } else { 
            return n;
        }
        //REVIEW: code optimization .. shrink version
        // message = ('Stephen' === name) ? "Welcome back Stephen" : "Welcome " + name;
  }

 $scope.numberOfPages=function(itemsPerPage){
        if (itemsPerPage == -1) itemsPerPage=$scope.coffees.length;
    return Math.ceil($scope.coffees.length/itemsPerPage);              
  }
}
```

Any idea why I might be getting the following [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXHFU.png)

**Update**
Have the following html snippet code:

```
<div class="row-fluid"> 
    <ul class="coffees">
      <li class="span4 coffeeitem" ng-repeat="coffee in (filteredItems = (coffees | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | filter:orderType | startFrom: (currentPage*resultspp)-resultspp | limitTo: showNresults(resultspp)))">
        <a href="#/coffees/{{coffee.id}}">{{coffee.name}}</a>
        <p>{{coffee.basicInfo}}</p>
        <button class="coffeebutton" type="button">Add to list</button>
      </li>
      <p ng-show="(coffees | filter:query).length == 0" id="message">No coffee found, please refine your search</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And have nailed down to the following that is causing me the circular dependency error `startFrom: (currentPage*resultspp)-resultspp | limitTo: showNresults(resultspp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `$scope.coffees`.

Just put this somewhere in your `CoffeeListCtrl`:

```
$scope.coffees = [];
```

What's happening is `$scope.numberOfPages` is getting evaluated before the `data/coffee.json` file is finished loading. By initializing the `coffees` property you ensure that the array exists when calling the `numberOfPages` function.

Comment: Makes sense enough, create a empty scoped array of coffees. Following what you suggested I still bugs out https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6476625 and my output is this: http://i.imgur.com/l0bBw4C.png

Comment: That's a separate issue. It looks like it has something to do with your HTML markup. You should also be defining your controller with the `module.controller` method. You can chain it right after the `config` call you have in app.js

Comment: If you get a circular dependency error in your console window what is this usually to do with? The following html block is the only thing that is causing me this issue.

Comment: I believe the cause of this because I never registered the startFrom as a dependency

Comment: You need to register the startFrom filter either directly with your module, or with its own module and then register that module as a dependency of your main module.